# Understanding Godement's criterion on quotient manifolds

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a manifold and $R\subset X\times X$ be an equivalence relation. Let $X/R$ be the set of equivalence classes and let $p:X\rightarrow X/R$ be the projection. Give $X/R$ the quotient topology. It is known that there is at most one manifold structure on $X/R$ such that $p$ is a submersion. In page 92, of Serre's book "Lie algebras and Lie groups" Springer LNM 1500, there is a criterion for $X/R$ to be a manifold, which is named after Godement and says the following. The quotient $X/R$ is a manifold if and only if

1, $R$ is a sub manifold of $X\times X$ (which means $R\rightarrow X\times X$ is a closed embedding), and

2, the projection map $pr_2:R\rightarrow X$ is a submersion.

This criterion looks very powerful since it gives an iff condition. On the other hand, it also works for non-archimedean local fields. In the usual textbook on manifolds, there is a quotient theorem which requires the action is free and proper. The freeness seems too restrictive. For example, the modular curve $H/\textrm{SL}_2(\textbf{Z})$ exists, where $H$ is upper half plane, but the action of $\textrm{SL}_2(\textbf{Z})$ is not free.

Since this criterion is not very common in the standard textbook on manifolds, I really would like to see how we apply this criterion to solve problems. Does anybody know a reference which contains a lot of examples on the application of this criterion?

I am also very interested in the following special case. Let $G$ be a compact Lie group which acts on a manifold $X$. Do we know that there exists a $G$-invariant open subset $X_o\subset X$ such that $X-X_o$ has lower dimension and $X_o/G$ exists as a manifold? Is this something standard from the Godement's criterion? How about when the field is non-archimedean?

In my other post, [Quotient of $\textrm{GL}(2,\textbf{R})$ by the conjugate action of $\textrm{SO}(2,\textbf{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924189/quotient-of-textrmgl2-textbfr-by-the-conjugate-action-of-textrmso) , I asked if the quotient $GL_2(R)/SO_2(R)$ exists as a manifold where $SO_2(R)$ acts on $GL_2(R)$ by conjugation. I got a nice answer from @YCor. But I also would like to know if it is possible to solve that problem using Godement's criterion.

The Godement's criterion is also mentioned in one answer of this question [Under what conditions the quotient space of a manifold is a manifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496571/under-what-conditions-the-quotient-space-of-a-manifold-is-a-manifold)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to your last question. Let $X$ be a manifold on which acts the compact Lie group $G$,  the orbits $G.x$ of $x$ and $G.y$ of $y$ have the same type if the stabilizers of $x$ is conjugated to the stabilizer of $y$. There exists a notion of principal orbit type. The union of principal orbits is an open subset of $U$ of $X$ and the quotient of $U$ by $G$ is a manifold.

See p.18 of https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/math661/LectureNotesLee.pdf

The proof here assume that $G$ preserves a differentiable metric a fact which is always true if $G$ is compact.